# how to find keyboard in /dev on osx

Tags: macos, keyboard, hook, driver, ioctl

On linux / ubuntu, the keyboard and mouse devices are found 
in /dev/input/by-path/
Where is the keyboard device mounted in osx? 
I added a usb keyboard, and no devices got added in /dev folder. 
Is it located somewhere else, or is it totally unaccessible? 
Thanks.

Edit: 
I was able to get some info on the keyboard using libusb: 
046d:c315 (bus 26, device 3)
and usb prober in developer tools from apple... 
however none of them mention a /dev special file or another way to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X uses its own system to manage the PNP device tree, see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html?section=Topics&topic=Drivers%2C%20Kernel%2C%20%26amp%3B%20Hardware&kind=topic to get started

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is not working any more. Could you please share some more information?